# How to assign struct values in a template class function?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, factory

I have a bunch of structures that I need to add to my vectors and give them some default values.

1. Structures are external, I can not change them.
2. While assigning these values, I need to see struct member names for convenience.
3. I need to have all default values visually at the same place for convenience.
4. Compiler currently optimizes away unused if branches in myClass::addStruct() - which is exactly what I want.

Q: can it be done in a better/simpler way?

**EDIT** I don't have C++17

// external structs

```
typedef struct A {
    int member1;
    float member2;
    char *member3;
    // ...
} A;

typedef struct B {
    double member5;
    float member3;
    int *member4;
    // ...
} B;

typedef struct C {
    char* member5;
    char* member2;
    float *member3;
    // ...
} C;

...

template <class T>
void myClass::addStruct(std::vector<T> &vp)
{
    void *sp = nullptr;
    if(std::is_same<T, A>::value) {
        A s{};
        s.member1 = 2;
        s.member3 = "whatever";
        sp = &s;
    }
    else if(std::is_same<T, B>::value) {
        B s{};
        s.member4 = nullptr;
        s.member3 = 3.1f;
        sp = &s;
    }
    else if(std::is_same<T, C>::value) {
        C s{};
        s.member2 = "whenever";
        sp = &s;
    }
/*  else if() {
    }
    else if() {
    } ...
*/

    if(sp == nullptr) {
        // print error
        return;
    }

    vp.push_back(*(reinterpret_cast<T*>(sp)));
}

// usage

addStruct<A>(...);
addStruct<A>(...);
addStruct<B>(...);
addStruct<C>(...);
```

Comment: try explicit template specialisation

Comment: dangling pointers should/may/will give you problems. To avoid, you must create the objects on the heap.

Comment: @xaxxon Because it won't compile without if constexpr ;)

Comment: @Trass3r if you put the cast for the vector in each branch of the if it should work.. cast whatever type to type T.. but it only actually happen when it was correct.

Answer (score 8):

1. Code like this shouldn't even compile unless you use if constexpr (aka "static if"). It only "works" because you break the type system (the whole void* and reinterpret_cast dance). [Type aliasing rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) apply.
2. You are taking the address of objects which have already gone out of scope. That's [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) and while working now could break at any point when changing the code or compiler or just compiler version.
3. If you really want to go with that code why wouldn't you just create non-template overloads for the different types? Way easier.

Comment: That it compiles says nothing - you are escaping the type system with `void*`. That it works says nothing - undefined behavior also includes the possibility of "everything works (for now)". In this case, it is very clear that you are in UB land: `sp` points to a stack variable (e.g. `A s`) that has 100% gone out of scope by the time you do the `push_back`.

Comment: @Max what exactly causes undefined behavior in the code?

Comment: @user1481126 Derefencing a pointer to an object that is no longer alive.

Comment: This part `*(reinterpret_cast<T*>(sp))`. It may even be double UB because it also breaks strict aliasing I think

Comment: @Trass3r How is that different to dereferencing a `void*` that you put some callback user data into? Afaik that's not UB...

Comment: @MaxLanghof this line `sp = &s;` creates a pointer to `s` that goes out of scope on the next line at the `}`. `sp` is now a dangling pointer.

Comment: @RichardCritten I know, and I said that twice already. I was talking about the suggested strict aliasing violation.

Comment: @Max A callback pointer is cast back to the correct type. Hence no UB.

Comment: @Trass3r But in this case it would be cast from e.g. `B*` to `void*` and back to `T*` which is `B*` in that case. That's the correct type, no?

Comment: _"Code like this shouldn't even compile, except for the parts where you wrote the code correctly so that it compiles"_

Comment: There is no aliasing problem here. The dangling pointers are obviously very bad. Other than that the OP's about got it right. I would recommend SFINAE here in the absence of `if constexpr` but ewwww

Comment: Ah, Jarod's got it with the tag dispatching.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <vector>

typedef struct A {
    int member1;
    float member2;
    const char *member3;
    // ...
} A;

typedef struct B {
    double member5;
    float member3;
    int *member4;
    // ...
} B;

typedef struct C {
    char* member5;
    char* member2;
    float *member3;
    // ...
} C;

template <class T>
void addStruct(std::vector<T> &vp)
{
    // print error
}

template <>
void addStruct<A>(std::vector<A> &vp)
{
    A s{};
    s.member1 = 2;
    s.member3 = "whatever";
    vp.push_back(s);
}

template <>
void addStruct<B>(std::vector<B> &vp)
{
    B s{};
    s.member4 = nullptr;
    s.member3 = 3.1f;
    vp.push_back(s);
}

// ...
```

**UPD after Trass3r:**

```
#include <vector>

typedef struct A {
    int member1;
    float member2;
    const char *member3;
    // ...
} A;

typedef struct B {
    double member5;
    float member3;
    int *member4;
    // ...
} B;

typedef struct C {
    char* member5;
    char* member2;
    float *member3;
    // ...
} C;

void addStruct(std::vector<A> &vp)
{
    A s{};
    s.member1 = 2;
    s.member3 = "whatever";
    vp.push_back(s);
}

void addStruct(std::vector<B> &vp)
{
    B s{};
    s.member4 = nullptr;
    s.member3 = 3.1f;
    vp.push_back(s);
}

// ...
```

Comment: and yes, as @Trass3r mentioned, it can be done without templates

Comment: you should be std::move()'ing s into the vector.  Or just default constructing it in the vector directly and then populating it in place - no move needed at all then.

Comment: @xaxxon there will be nothing to move actually (I hope =) ), default constructing in the vector - looks like an optimal way

Comment: `auto & s = v.emplace_back();` -- oops, he doesn't have c++17... `v.emplace_back(); auto & s = v.back();`

Comment: @xaxxon Is the emplace version guaranteed to zero-initialize the object?

Comment: Please _explain_ your answer rather than just dumping code.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it's a matter of personal taste. Sometimes short but effective answer is better than time-consuming-to-read-but-allowing-an-author-to-feel-smarter essay

Comment: @wtom It is not a matter of personal taste. A code dump without any explanation is _more harmful_ than no answer at all. It has nothing to do with "allowing an author to feel smarter". What use is your suggestion if you did not explain why it's better than the original code, how it fixes the problem, and what the problem was?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit OK. What specifically is not clear here for you? I'll try to explain.

Comment: @wtom It's not for me. It's for the OP and for future visitors. I already listed the things you should explain in a good answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Let's OP and future visitors decide what is better for them. They always can write in comments what is not clear. Then it will be the fact that answer is not complete enough and I'll correct it. Otherwise it is an attempt to intrude your personal opinion and/or punish people that don't follow your mental template. It is what is really harmful )

Answer (score 2):

Create factory methods:

```
template <typename T> struct Tag {};

A MakeDefault(Tag<A>) {
    A a{};
    a.member1 = 2;
    a.member3 = "whatever";
    return a;
}

B MakeDefault(Tag<B>) {
    B b{};
    b.member4 = nullptr;
    b.member3 = 3.1f;
    return b;
}

C MakeDefault(Tag<C>) {
    C c{};
    c.member2 = "whenever";
    return c;
}

// ...

template <class T>
void myClass::addStruct(std::vector<T> &vp)
{
    vp.push_back(MakeDefault(tag<T>{}));
}
```

I use tag dispatching instead of template specialization which seems simpler here.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: can it be done in a better/simpler way?

Yes: It can be done without templates, by using functional polymorphism (functions with the same name and different arguments).

```
typedef struct A {
    int member1;
    float member2;
    char *member3;
    // ...
} A;

typedef struct B {
    double member5;
    float member3;
    int *member4;
    // ...
} B;

...

void myClass::addStruct(std::vector<A>& v)
{
    v.push_back({0});
    v.back().member1 = 2;
    v.back().member3 = "whatever";
}

void myClass::addStruct(std::vector<B>& v)
{
    v.push_back({0});
    // v.back().member4 = nullptr; // this is unnecessary now
    v.back().member3 = 3.1f;
}

...

// usage

std::vector<A> va;
std::vector<B> vb;

myClass c;
c.addStruct(va);
c.addStruct(vb);
```

Comment: Please _explain_ your answer rather than just dumping code.